# Move data from Sqlite to Core data in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sqlite, core-data

I am working on app which is in  `objective -C`. Now i migrate that app in Swift. Now m facing the problem is that the older version is saving some data in local database using `SQLite`. But in my new version I am using `CoreData` to save local data. So I want to retain previous data too in new version. Any suggestion to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a migration to run on startup and copy the data from the old location to the new location.